CIFilter on AVPlayerItem: Chroma key filter make pixels become black instead of transparent
I followed this document to make a chroma key filter for AVPlayerItem on iOS. I want all pixels that match a condition become transparent. For now, the condition is whether the pixel has hue value between 0.3 and 0.4 (green pixels).
My filter:
- (CGFloat) hueFromRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue {
    UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1];
    
    CGFloat hue, saturation, brightness;
    [color getHue:&hue saturation:&saturation brightness:&brightness alpha:nil];
    
    return hue;
}

- (CIFilter<CIColorCube> *) chromaKeyFilterHuesFrom:(CGFloat)minHue to:(CGFloat)maxHue {
    const unsigned int size = 64;
    const size_t cubeDataSize = size * size * size * 4;
    NSMutableData* cubeData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:(cubeDataSize * sizeof(float))];
    
    for (int z = 0; z < size; z++) {
        CGFloat blue = ((double)z)/(size-1);
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            CGFloat green = ((double)y)/(size-1);
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                CGFloat red = ((double)x)/(size-1);
                
                CGFloat hue = [self hueFromRed:red green:green blue:blue];
                float alpha = (hue >= minHue && hue <= maxHue) ? 0 : 1;
                float premultipliedRed = red * alpha;
                float premultipliedGreen = green * alpha;
                float premultipliedBlue = blue * alpha;
                [cubeData appendBytes:&premultipliedRed length:sizeof(float)];
                [cubeData appendBytes:&premultipliedGreen length:sizeof(float)];
                [cubeData appendBytes:&premultipliedBlue length:sizeof(float)];
                [cubeData appendBytes:&alpha length:sizeof(float)];
            }
        }
    }

    CIFilter<CIColorCube> *colorCubeFilter = CIFilter.colorCubeFilter;
    colorCubeFilter.cubeDimension = size;
    colorCubeFilter.cubeData = cubeData;
    return colorCubeFilter;
}

In ViewController, I created a button to start the video player and apply the filter to AVPlayerItem. [self chromaKeyFilterHuesFrom:0.3 to:0.4] means filtering the green pixels:
- (AVVideoComposition*) createVideoComposition:(AVPlayerItem *)_playerItem {
    CIFilter<CIColorCube>* chromaKeyFilter = [self chromaKeyFilterHuesFrom:0.3 to:0.4];
    AVMutableVideoComposition *composition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoCompositionWithAsset: _playerItem.asset applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:^(AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest *_Nonnull request) {
        CIImage *image = request.sourceImage.imageByClampingToExtent;
        [chromaKeyFilter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
        CIImage *output = [chromaKeyFilter.outputImage imageByCroppingToRect:request.sourceImage.extent];
        [request finishWithImage:output context:nil];
    }];
    
    return composition;
}

- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my_video_has_green_pixels_zone" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
    playerItem.videoComposition = [self createVideoComposition:playerItem];
    
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
    
    AVPlayerViewController *controller =  [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    controller.player = player;
    controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
    [[self view] addSubview:controller.view];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    
    [player play];
}

The filter works "fine", except that the greens pixels become black instead of transparent. I can't figure out why or what makes those pixels become black.
UPDATE
I tried Frank's suggestion and changed from AVPlayerViewController to AVPlayerLayer, it's now working.
NSDictionary* pixelBufferAttributes = @{ (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) };

AVPlayerLayer *layerPlayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
    layerPlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    layerPlayer.frame = self.view.frame;
    layerPlayer.pixelBufferAttributes = pixelBufferAttributes;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layerPlayer];

However, this is still not what I want since I have to use AVPlayerViewController.

The pixel buffers used by the AVPlayerViewController probably don't support the alpha channel by default (to save memory). But you can change the pixel format like this:
AVPlayerViewController *controller =  [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
controller.pixelBufferAttributes = @{kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA};


I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. However. if I replace AVPlayerViewController with AVPlayerLayer, everything works as expected! I updated the question.
